# ProxyKit and Querystring for WebSocket connection

Tags: signalr, reverse-proxy, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using ProxyKit to act as a reverse proxy.  I need to proxy http and websocket (signalR) traffic so I have the below configuration.  I also need to send across a querystring, what do I need to add to the base configuration to also include the querystring, I've tried this:

```
    var redirectTo = "https://proxied-server:5002";
    var wssredirectTo = "ws://proxied-server:5002";

    app.UseWebSockets();

    app.UseWebSocketProxy(context => new Uri(wssredirectTo + context.Request.Path.ToString() + context.Request.QueryString.ToString()),
        options => options.AddXForwardedHeaders());

    app.RunProxy(context =>
    {
        var finalUrl = redirectTo + context.Request.Path.ToString();
        var finalContext = context.ForwardTo(finalUrl);
        finalContext.UpstreamRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(finalUrl);

        return finalContext
            .CopyXForwardedHeaders()
            .AddXForwardedHeaders()
            .Send();
    });
```

But I still only see the root url in the proxied server kestrel log:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://proxied-server:5002/signal/satellite/negotiate text/plain; charset=UTF-8 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 2.3528ms 200 application/json
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://proxied-server:5002/signal/satellite
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 2.3958ms 400 text/plain
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to set `RequestUri` directly <sup>1,2</sup>:

```cs
app.RunProxy(context => context
    .ForwardTo(redirectTo)
    .CopyXForwardedHeaders()
    .AddXForwardedHeaders()
    .Send());
```

## Explanation

ProxyKit already handles `context.Request.QueryString` in `ForwardTo` <sup>3</sup>:

> ```cs
> var uri = new Uri(UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(
>     upstreamHost.Scheme,
>     upstreamHost.Host,
>     upstreamHost.PathBase,
>     context.Request.Path,
>     context.Request.QueryString));
> ```

## References

1. https://github.com/proxykit/ProxyKit#12-forward-http-requests
2. https://github.com/proxykit/ProxyKit#233-copying-x-forwarded-headers
3. https://github.com/proxykit/ProxyKit/blob/4468429f3910111b98d80821fd10824204573053/src/ProxyKit/HttpContextExtensions.cs#L21-L26

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm not having an issue with the standard http call, my full uri is being transferred.  The problem is the ws: calls.

Do I need to add something to this?

  app.UseWebSocketProxy(context => new Uri(wssredirectTo + context.Request.Path.ToString() + context.Request.QueryString.ToString()),
        options => options.AddXForwardedHeaders());